# How do I display notifications from web browser Developer Tools with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This display notice in the browser, which I want to ask how to display it (e.g. with console.log) or call it with a function?

[image]
<sup>**Chrome -> ⋮ -> More tools -> Developer Tools -> Network tab**</sup>

This is the code that I made to call the URL address, I use redux and await async

[image]

This code display is called from number 2, which I want to ask how to display the notice here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the message out of the error object you have to put `error.response.data.message`.

If you console.log(error.response.data.message) the error message can be logged.

Comment: this.setState({status:err.response.data.message});